What "skylight" is Seq referring to?
In The Matrix Resurrections (2021), the screen shows green-colored code on display:

[woman] Seq, I'm in.
[Seq] Captain. You were right. The skylight was a window pane. I've
got serious interference.

What "skylight" is Seq referring to?

One that they found that has a weird modal inside of it.
